# How can I mass delete all the files in a directory that contain only one line?

Tags: file-recovery

I used a data recovery program to recover a bunch of overwritten text and the stuff that I want (previous versions of the overwritten files) is hidden amongst thousands of `.txt`, `.json`, `.h` and `.html` files.

Most of these unwanted files contain only one line of garbled text (even if they are megabytes in size), so it would be useful to have a tool that can quickly recognize those files and eliminate them.

(For background: some of the text that I want has been found within these recovered files, sometimes amidst truncated lines of code or complete garbage. No files containing only one line contain the text that I want, therefore I want those files to be eliminated.)

Comment: for clarification, some of the text that i want has been found within these recovered files, sometimes amidst truncated lines of code or complete garbage. no files containing only one line contain the text that i want, therefore i want those files to be eliminated.

Comment: do you know about bash? try using bash

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: whoops; this is for vista. i am unfamiliar with bash but eager to learn. i'll try out that bash script with a linux livecd later today, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You used `photorec` for the recovery, didn't you?

You didn't specify an OS but I'm going to assume **Linux** anyway.

Save script to **/root/removebadfiles.sh** (and `chmod +x /root/removebadfiles.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$@"
lines=$(wc -l "$file" 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}');
if [ "$lines" = "1" ]; then 
  echo "$file"; 
  rm "$file"; 
fi
```

Recursive one-liner:

```
cd /path/to/files
find -type f -exec /root/removebadfiles.sh {} \;
```